# How to count number of occurences of a word in a multi-line variable in a bash script

Tags: bash, variables, count, var

I have a bash script, which reads from a command into a var.

something like

```
status="$(somescript.sh 2>&1)" #yeah the script prints to STDERR with RC=0...
```

variable status contains something like:

```
bla bla
-------
123 OK
456 OK
789 OK
```

Now I simply want to count the number of occurences of "OK" in the var status, so I can later check, if count is -lt 3

I've tried with making an array from the var status with IFS=..., but something doesn't work on assignment,

I've tried grep + wc within the bash script,

I've tried tr within the script, but something with var status expansion fails,

and all the examples on the net are for reading from a file, not a var.

But I'm in a bash script reading from a bash variable.

Comment: `grep -iFc 'OK' <<< "$status"` should work.

Comment: Many thanks, that works. Note, that the resulting number needs to be decreased by 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -o 'OK' <<< $status |  wc -l
```

Demo:

```
-------
123 OK
456 OK
789 OK' 
$grep -o 'OK' <<< $var 
OK
OK
OK
$grep -o 'OK' <<< $var  |  wc -l
3
$
```